# How to iterate all QPushButton in a QGroupBox

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots, qpushbutton, qgroupbox

I have a QDialog which contains a QGroupBox which in turn contains some push-buttons. I want to differentiate the background-color of the push-button which is clicked and all the remaining push-buttonx. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the buttons are all children of the group-box, and then use [findChildren](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) to iterate over them. You could also use a [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) to help manage the buttons.

Here's a demo script to show how it could be done:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.groupBox)
        for index in range(5):
            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button %d' % index, self.groupBox)
            layout.addWidget(button)
        self.buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self)
        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.handleButtonClicked)
        self.updateButtonGroup()

    def updateButtonGroup(self):
        for button in self.groupBox.findChildren(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
            if self.buttonGroup.id(button) < 0:
                self.buttonGroup.addButton(button)

    def handleButtonClicked(self, button):
        for item in self.buttonGroup.buttons():
            if button is item:
                item.setStyleSheet('background-color: orange')
            else:
                item.setStyleSheet('')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Dialog()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

If reason to use class [`QtGui.QGroupBox`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgroupbox.html) is select button just like radio button, You can use Qt Style Sheet to set difference background color;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QCustomDialog (QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        myQVBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        for text in ['PyQt', 'Stack', 'Overflow']:
            myQPushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(text)
            myQPushButton.setCheckable(True)
            myQPushButton.setAutoExclusive(True)
            myQVBoxLayout.addWidget(myQPushButton)
        myQVBoxLayout.addStretch(1)
        myQGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox()
        myQGroupBox.setStyleSheet('''
            QPushButton {
                border: 0px;
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            }
            QPushButton:checked {
                border: 0px;
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
            }
        ''')
        myQGroupBox.setLayout(myQVBoxLayout)
        allQVBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        allQVBoxLayout.addWidget(myQGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(allQVBoxLayout)

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQCustomDialog = QCustomDialog()
myQCustomDialog.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Comment: I just want to iterate all buttons[without hard coding the buttonNames in 'For loop'. Because in future new buttons may be add or removed] and Highlight(backcolor) the clicked once dynamically